# "Skip Intro" link over HTML5 video not working on iPad

Tags: ipad, html, html5-video

I am using the "[Javascript Fake Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5)" script to autoplay an introductory HTML5 video on an iPad, which then directs to a landing page.

I have a simple "skip intro" link on top of the video element in a higher z-index. This link works in other browsers, but not on the iPad (iOS 3.2.2).

I think it may have to do with the click event on a video on the iPad defaulting to pause/play the video. Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the same problem I had. The video tag will capture all the events when the controls attribute is added to the video tag.. Try removing the controls attribute...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the javascript hack doesn't work on iOS 4 and above.
Apple forces all videos on iOS to start only from user input, so "autoplay" doesn't work either. If you remove the "controls" attribute, the video won't even start playing. What you're trying to accomplish isn't acctually possible (considering all the iOS versions...)

Answer (score 1):

I made something like that.  I used this function:

```
    function videoEnd() {
        $('#mainVideo').fadeOut('slow');
        window.location = "/home.aspx";
    }
```

Works fine on the iPAD.