# html5 <audio> not playing on IOS Safari

Tags: ios, ipad, html, safari

I have an mp3 which plays correctly via the embed tag in older browsers, but for iPad, when I try to play the same mp3 via `<audio>`, it says movie not supported. Is this a MIME type issue?  This method works on desktop Safari.

How do I get it to play on Safari under IOS4.3?

Here's my code:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');  
audio.type = "audio/mpeg";     
audio.src = audioUrl;              
x.appendChild(audio);     
audio.load(); 
audio.play();
```

Comment: What does your markup for the audio element look like?

Comment: I have added the code in my orig question..

Comment: Well, this should work - you're already specifying the MIME setting when you set the type attribute. If you're able to play it on your desktop, then it's not a server-side issue that would require modifying .htaccess either. That you can play HTML5 audio from other sources make it even more perplexing. I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: Yes exactly..that is what..I have tried almost all that I could think of..Not sure why it is not playing..

Comment: You need to take care about start buffering look at this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378805/mp4-video-in-html5-video-tag-not-playing-in-mobile-chrome-and-mobile-safari/42268108#42268108

Comment: Make sure you are using full file path and not relative file path.  That's what did it for me.

Answer (score 9):

As of 4.x iOS no longer supports autoplay for html5 audio objects. 
See: [Autoplay audio files on an iPad with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5)

edit (2011-10-04): This was regarding to how the original posters code snippet was presented. If given code is not executed via an event triggered by user action (f.ex click), the audio won't play. If you have this code inside a function that is bound to click event on some button, it should work (haven't tested).

Comment: This was not a question about autoplay.

Comment: Ok by the looks of the code snippet I assumed that this was the case. Edited and clarified my answer.

Comment: This answer is right on: the question is why this code doesn't work on iOS. The answer is: because Apple has blocked <audio> elements from playing without user interaction. They've blocked auto play.

Comment: Well, the situation still there without autoplay as well .. a similar code I used, doesn't play ... just mute .. only iOS .. and now we are at 12.x.x not matter Chrome vs Safari ... and it's quite annoyng

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the load has to happen in a user-triggered event (button click, etc). I'm not sure which iOS version this is, but I confirmed it in 4.3.5. I've written up a bit more details and a possible workaround here:

[Autoplay audio files on an iPad with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5/8001076#8001076)

Edit: Apple's explanation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

So the issue is iOS 4+

Answer (score 3):

I have to add something to the answer by kinakuta

I tried the link in the comment to the answer [apples html5 showcase](http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/audio/)
The music plays with Firefox 16, Internet Explorer 9, Google Chrome 22 and Opera if you mask Opera as firefox.

But Apples OWN Demo DOES NOT WORK with Apple Safari 5.1.7 on my Machine because I don't have Quicktime on my machine.
HTML5 Audio is not working very well with Safari, there are others having trouble with it.
this can be irritation during development If one does not want quicktime installed on the computer.

Comment: Technically, what happens is that Safari relies on QuickTime to play audio (at least on Windows, can't speak for MacOS). So, no QT, no audio.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are serving the content over https you need to have a valid certificate or it will not play on iOS devices (or on Safari on a Mac). You won't get an SSL error or any obvious SSL related messages -- it just won't work on iOS devices and Safari for the Mac, but will work for Chrome and Firefox (for example) on a Mac.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365535/html5-audio-playback-over-https-on-safari-iphone-4-3) for a related question where SSL was the issue (as it was for me).

Answer (score 0):

Good news everybody

I read somewhere that once you’ve played the sound once on a user interaction,
you can then play it again without further interaction.

So set volume to zero and play all loaded sounds in one go at start.

I had a listener on 'touchstart' with a single instantiated function
that played all the sounds once the user touches the screen.

Here's how I did it in my REACT componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() 
{
    
    let that = this;
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(evt) //First touch event on the screen will trigger this
        { 
            console.log("Audio Setup for iOS:", that.state.allow_sound);
            if(!that.state.allow_sound) //False on initial load
            {
                var Audio1 = document.getElementById("ping");
                Audio1.load();  
                Audio1.volume = 0;
                Audio1.play();          
                
                var Audio2 = document.getElementById("boom");
                Audio2.load();  
                Audio2.volume = 0;
                Audio2.play();  
                        
                var Audio3 = document.getElementById("splash");
                Audio3.load();  
                Audio3.volume = 0;
                Audio3.play();          
                
                var Audio4 = document.getElementById("hit");
                Audio4.load();  
                Audio4.volume = 0;
                Audio4.play();                          

                that.setState({allow_sound : true})
            }
    });
}

Then you can call these sounds dynamically from within the code.
```