# playing an ogg sound after loading website

Tags: jquery, html

I want to play an ogg file after loading my website by calling a jquery function.How can i do this ??

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function(){

      // here i want to call this function to play my sound.

  });
</script>
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
    function play()            {
    var audio=document.getElementById('audio1');
    audio.play();
                   }
           $(window).load(function(){
            play();
                                   });
```

in HTML

```
<audio id="audio1" style="display:none;">
<source src="Audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="Audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="Audio.mp3">
</audio>
```