# How play music from php without quick time player

Tags: ios, quicktime

I have question. How play music from php/html and others without quicktime player. When i pushed to button in php with mp3 url my iPhone open automaticly quicktime player. But i need only play music from site without quicktimeplayer. How it's make saying please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `<audio>` tag. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/226992/Back-Ground-Music-in-Html5

If you don't want to play it immediately, leave off the `autoplay` attribute and call the .play() function at a later point. (See also: [Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript))

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) and see if it helps. I'm not familiar with iOS safari and don't have a device available to test on.