# How do I make a sound play once on document ready?

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted a nice and simple way to play a sound once, right when the document is ready.

As I searched for clues online I found a lot, but none were that explanatory, so what I am asking is for some help on **how to build this on the most browser compatible and light way**.

Thanks ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing audio with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Use this Markup

```
<audio id="sound_tag" src="your_audio_file.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sound_tag')[0].play();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice one, a little different from what I had already, simpler too ;)