# Playing audio to sockets node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, audio

I have a node.js app which should plays 3 sounds to all of the sockets at a certain time with node.js.

How would I go about getting this to work? Should I have the sound clips on the app.js and somehow emit them? Or should I have them stored in the client Side HTML and a flag to play them emitted to the users?

Could I see examples of how to do the prefered method also? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make the 3 audio files public (for example `/public/audio/1.mp3` and relative node routes) and then to split the problem in 2 sub-problems:

- The first is HOW to play the audio in JavaScript? [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)
- The second is WHEN to play the audio?

For example if you're using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) I suggest you this simple code (server side):

```
io.emit('play', { audio: '/public/audio/1.mp3'});
```

And, for example, this can be the client side code needed:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on('play', function (data) {
    // Here goes the 'HOW' piece of code
    // to play the data.audio track
});
```