# Inject script to play audio file if InnerText does not match string

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, client-side-scripting

I need to monitor a webpage for new events. The page shows a string ("No events") if no events are available. This page reloads automatically every minute. This page will often be in the background, but I wan't to be notified events are available, because I need to respond to them.

This is what I've come up with so far, and this works. I use the Chrome "Custom JavaScript for websites" to run the below code.

```
var element = document.getElementById('queue').innerText;
if (element !== "No events") {
    window.alert("ALARM!ALARM!");
}
```

However, instead of a alert popup, I would like a local audio file to play.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This.

```
var element = document.getElementById('queue').innerText;
if (element != "No events") 
{
    var audio = new Audio('AAA.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

**Note:**

The **extension** of your audio(.mp3) and the associated **content types** must be added in **MIME** types in **IIS**