# Playing multiple mp3s files in one player

Tags: html, mp3

In HTML5 I want to do a list of mp3s for our clinets. Firstly I createad a simple HTML table and crated player object in front of each record. As the count of files are growing, browsers starts to hang up when I show so many objects on the list.

How can I crate one player and just send a file to play by user click to that player? I think it is how it is should be, but I can't find any JS examles. Could anybody help please?

Thanks

Comment: `<audio id="player" src="rickroll.mp3">` then just change the src: `document.getElementById('player').src = 'othertune.mp3';`

Comment: Wow. That;s fast! Thanks a lot Marc.

Comment: And when I changed the source how can I start play this file?

Comment: Thanks, I already found your previous post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript