# How do I make music play when image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, image, click

I have an image that changes the background of the page already but I would also like it to play music when I click the image.
Here's My code

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
        <div id="box">
            <div class="button">
                <img src="alien.png" type="button" id="my-button">
                <br>
                <p>Click The Alien!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 <script>
var myData = {

        1: {
        imageUrl: "8.gif",

        },

};

function changeImage() {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
        document.getElementById("background").style.background = "url('" + myData[randomNumber].imageUrl + "')";
        document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML = myData[randomNumber].text;
}
    document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", changeImage);
```

Comment: `<audio>` or `<video>` Elements will have to be used. Flash (ActionScript) will also have to be used if your Client doesn't have HTML5.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript][1] Check all the answers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how well the Javascript Audio API is implemented in your chosen browser, you can use the AudioContext interface, documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.

Answer (score -2):

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
       $(document).("click", "img.class", function() {
          var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');  //creates audio element
          audioElement.setAttribute('src', audiopath);         //setpath to audio files.
          audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');   //set auto play attributes.
          audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
             audioElement.Play();                              //plays audio element.
          }, true);
       });
    });
```

Use audioElement for it.

Comment: What a terrible mess. Why is the indentation _all over the place_? What is `$.get()` supposed to do? Why do you have a commented-out line? Where is the explanation of your proposed solution? It truly baffles me that this nonsense has an upvote.