# Playing sound from INACTIVE browser tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, browser

I have a control panel for restaurants and it plays an alert sound when an order is given. The problem is that when the control panel tab is not the active tab in Chrome (it's also same for Firefox) the alert sound doesn't play. After clicking the tab it plays the sound.

I see some sites (Facebook Chat, Cloudstats.me server alert, ...) play sound even if they are in inactive tab, so what is the workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Had a similar thing happen to me as well, we were trying to play a marketclock when the stock market opened and closed for the day. The issue we had was we tried to load the mp3 then play it when the condition is met. So originally I had.

```
var bell;

// Update the clock, countdown, and tooltips as needed.
function updateClock() {
    service.getMarketDate(function(data) {

        if (data.soundMarketBell) {
            if (!bell) {
                bell = new Audio('/sounds/marketclock.mp3');
            }
            bell.play();
        }
    });
}

var intervalId = $interval(updateClock, 1000);
```

By moving the resource loading to happen on page load and then just calling the Audio.play it fixed the issue

```
var bell = new Audio('/sounds/marketclock.mp3');

// Update the clock, countdown, and tooltips as needed.
function updateClock() {
    service.getMarketDate(function(data) {
        if (data.soundMarketBell) {
            bell.play();
        }
    });
}

// check for a time update every second
// to balance accuracy with performance
var intervalId = $interval(updateClock, 1000)
```

Browsers restrict loading resources when a tab is inactive

Comment: I would love to see some documentation on this:  "Browsers restrict loading resources when a tab is inactive"

Comment: I'm not sure the explanation is correct. it takes time to download the mp3 file, so for the first time (at least), the Audio object isn't ready causing "play" to fail. moving the line to the top of the script loads the file immediately once the script is loaded so the file is available for playing.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the possibility that the audio wouldn't play because of browsers Autoplay policy.

For example, in Chrome the audio won't play until the user actively click the web page.

you may find the full list here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes