# How to set custom notification sound in Notification API in JS

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

I want to show push notification from my web app in windows with custom sound like in WhatsApp Web. Also I want to accomplish this when the tab is inactive. So I can't use `Audio()` for playing my custom notification sound due to this [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039338/13396193).

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
```

I'm able to show notification with default sound with above code. But how to play custom tone ?