# How do I play a .wav upon having someone click a link

Tags: audio, hyperlink, click, wav, effect

I have a .wav that I want to play when a person clicks on a link. How do I go about doing that? I'm not exactly an expert at html or css or javascript so be gentle with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reference***

[Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

***Example***

Two Links

```
<a href='#' class="playButton">Play</a>
<a href='#' class="stopButton">Stop</a>
```

jQuery click Events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audio;
    $("a.playButton").click(function(){
        console.log("playing");
        audio = new Audio('http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/WAV/Media-   Convert/Media-Convert_test1_Alaw_Mono_VBR_8SS_16000Hz.wav');
        audio.play();
    });

    $("a.stopButton").click(function(){
        console.log("Pause");

        audio.pause();
    });

});
```

Now this probably isn't the most accurate way to do this but it gives you an idea of how this works. If you want to use the built in `audio` tag you can do that too cause that will give you the controls and other helpful things.

***JSFIDDLE***

https://jsfiddle.net/pzth1zd5/