# Play audio when clicking on button and redirect after sound is done playing

Tags: javascript, html, button, delay

I made I simple site with four buttons. If I click one I want it to play a sound and when the sound is done playing (or after 'X' amount of seconds) I want it to redirect.

This is my code so far. I have no idea on how to put in the sound and the delay.

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/level1/style.css">



</head>

<body>



<img STYLE= "top: 20px; Left: 200px; height:900px; width: 800px position:      absolute;" src="\images\border.jpg">
<img STYLE= "position: absolute; top: 50px; Left: 50px; height:120px; width:  120px;" src="\images\level1.jpg">

<a href="#"><img src="\images\1a1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='/images/1a1g.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='/images/1a1.jpg'"  id="a1"> </a>
<a href="\level1\index.html"><img src="\images\1a2.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='/images/1a2g.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='/images/1a2.jpg'" " id="a2"> </a>
<a href="\level1\index.html"><img src="\images\1a3.jpg"   onmouseover="this.src='/images/1a3g.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='/images/1a3.jpg'"  id="a3"> </a>
<a href="\level1\index.html"><img src="\images\1a4.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='/images/1a4g.jpg'"
onmouseout="this.src='/images/1a4.jpg'"  id="a4"> </a>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: Redirect where? To do what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed a HTML Audio Element:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

With the method play() in the eventlistener, as described on this page you can start the audio, when Audio playing has ended: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp
You can set a Timeout with

```
`var seconds= 3;
setTimeout(
        function(){
              /*  This code will be executed, after the defined Delay  */
              }
 seconds * 1000);`
```

Comment: Just set the Audio Element Attribute "preload" to true, then this problem can be fixe, if the user stays some seconds on the page, before starting the audio, but if this is not enough, you would have to block the event till the audio has loaded or just fire the redirect