# Fnd out all methods from an object

Tags: javascript, class, object, audio

I try to play audio with javascript. I already found out how to do so in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript):

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```

but there is no info on how to stop the audio again.

I tried `audio.stop()` but i get `index.php:133 Uncaught TypeError: audio.stop is not a function`
I was wondering how i can find out all available methods from an object?

Comment: Reading the manual is a good starting point: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement

Comment: How about [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)?

Comment: @Quentin: That's the spec, not a "manual"

Comment: But i searched for a code solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `for` loop and log each *key* contained within the object to the console:

```
var audio = new Audio();

for (var key in audio)
  console.log(key)
```

If you want to specifically find functions, you can extend this to check implement a `typeof` check:

```
for (var key in audio)
  if (typeof audio[key] === "function")
    console.log(key)
```

```js
var audio = new Audio();

for (var key in audio)
  if (typeof audio[key] === "function")
    document.write(key + "<br>")
```

Comment: …as long as the properties are enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

try `audio.pause();`

I found a list of methods for the audio object here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp

Comment: Whilst this is what OP should have used instead of `stop`, this doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: I found a list of methods for the audio object at w3schools. He asked how to find a list of methods for a javascript object. That is one simple way to do so.