# Can't get audio file to play when div is clicked

Tags: javascript

could someone please help me to understand why my audio won't play?

html:

```
<div id = "One" class = "square" onmousedown = "playSound(1)" ></div>
<audio id = "sound1" src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3"/>
```

JS:

```
function playSound(val) {
var soundToPlay = document.getElementByID("sound"+val);
soundToPlay.play();
}
```

Much appreciated :)

Comment: What happens when you place an alert at the top of your js function? Does it get triggered when you click the div?

Comment: Also, you are not reading the source properly. Try this: document.getElementByID("sound"+val).src;

Comment: Did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9419328/4879022 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo with a  uppercase `D` in `Id` here:

```
getElementByID
//-this -----^
```

change to this:

```
function playSound(val) {
    var soundToPlay = document.getElementById("sound"+val); // lowerCase "d" required
    soundToPlay.play();
}
```

Comment: That bugged me for hours. Thank you!