# Play audio when select options - Angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova

There's a way to play a sound like a beep when i select an option from the list below?

```
<select ng-model="orderList" class="meselect">

                <option value="Nm">Name</option>
                <option value="Tp">Type</option>
                <option value="Pr">Price</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: For very simple JS-based audio, you can look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript). You'd basically just be running that in a function called by ngClick.

Comment: Use the `ng-change` directive to invoke an audio function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript for this. 
Include this into your index.html within script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html5_audiotypes = {
    //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
    "ogg": "audio/ogg",
    "wav": "audio/wav"
};

function createsoundbite(sound) {
    var html5audio = document.createElement('audio');
    if (html5audio.canPlayType) { //check support for HTML5 audio
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var sourceel = document.createElement('source');
            sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i]);
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i)) {
                sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1]);
            }
            html5audio.appendChild(sourceel);
        }
        html5audio.load();
        html5audio.playclip = function() {
            html5audio.pause();
            html5audio.currentTime = 0;
            html5audio.play();
        }
        return html5audio;
    } else {
        return {
            playclip: function() {
                throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately");
            }
        };
    }
}
 // Provide path for sounds
clicksound = createsoundbite("/sounds/daClick.ogg", "/sounds/daClick.mp3");
coindropsound = createsoundbite("/sounds/coin-drop.ogg", "/sounds/coin-drop.mp3");
</script>
```

Once done you can call clicksound.playclip() on dropdown change event

Comment: But i'll use ng-click? And i want to use only one sound just a beep

Comment: This seems excessive for such a simple task.

Comment: @Leogreen - You have to add audio element to play audio.

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein was just a trouble about the event.

Comment: @Bhuneshwer thank you so much !                onchange="clicksound.playclip()