# Play sound when <div> is visible

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a delayed display div. I want to add sound when div is visible. How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deley").hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".deley").show();
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deley">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deley").hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".deley").show();
        $(".audioPlayer")[0].play();
        
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="deley">TEXT</div>
<audio class="audioPlayer">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="http://op.50megs.com/house!.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to include it in whatever event listener you're using to toggle the element's display value.

When hiding (i.e. `$(".deley").hide();`:

```
    $("#epicSound").pause();
    $('#epicSound").currentTime = 0;
```

When showing (i.e. `$('.deley').show()`):

```
    $("#epicSound").play();
```

Your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".deley").hide();
    // if sound is currently playing, stop it and reset
    if(!$("#epicSound").paused) {
        $("#epicSound").pause();
        $("#epicSound").currentTime = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".deley").show();
        $("#epicSound").play();            
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
<div class="deley">TEXT</div>
<audio id="epicSound">
  <source src="epicSound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="epicSound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: You've got an extra period before the hash in your first code example.