# Playing a sound as a value changes

Tags: meteor, web

I am developing a lobby for multiplayer online experiment. The lobby basically is a stage where the participants wait until we have the required number of people. I want to play a bell sound that I have in the project public directory `public/newPlayerSound.mp3` .. and I have the following helper:

```
Template.lobby_page.helpers({
    numWaiting(){
        if (Meteor.userId()){
            let lobby = Lobbies.findOne({players:Meteor.userId()});
            if (lobby){
                //play the newPlayerSound.mp3
                return lobby.players.length
            }
        }
    },
});
```

I want to play the `newPlayerSound.mp3` every-time the `numWaiting()` changes.  What would be an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what [Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378594/uri) has said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript), you can use [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement).

```
new Audio("newPlayerSound.mp3").play()
```