# HTML5 Sound not Working on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am facing a problem while playing sound in my website. I am applying the condition if data coming from db is equal to 1, sound should play, else it should stop .. Everything is working fine on Desktop but not working on mobile devices. here is my code below..any help will be appreciated.

HTML

```
<audio id="my_audio">
  <source src="../Beep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

JS

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url: "actions4.php",
      data:"",
      success:function(data)
      {     
        if(data == 0){
     $('audio').get(0).load();
      $('audio').get(0).paused();
        } else {
        $('audio').get(0).load();
        $('audio').get(0).play();                 

        }
      }
    });
}, 2000);//time in milliseconds
```

Comment: Look at this link on how to play audio.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: which mobile device are you testing it with? 
I think that most mobile browsers require a usergenerated gesture to autoplay? not sure though

Comment: testing on Android (Samsung Grand Prime) and IOS