# Countdown timer with sound (no buttons)

Tags: javascript, audio, timer, countdown

Im trying to create a simple countdown timer that plays a beep when it's done, or when reaches 0.

```
 <script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 31, 2018 00:00:00").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " h"
    + minutes + " m " + seconds + " sec";

    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Text";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: what is you problem ? is it you don't know how to play a sound ? there is no question in this post

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript) will help you