# How to play a sound when rss feed change on php

Tags: php, rss

I have this php which loads rss feed for Economic news. 
Is it possible to play a sound when the rss feed adds a new title?
I have not tried anything yet because i have no idea how to do it.
I suppose what i need to do is store the variable from title and then compare it and after that call a function on javascript to play the sound.

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://rss.dailyfx.com/feeds/alerts/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y, H:m', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a " title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em style="color:red; text-align:center;"> '.$date.'</em>    </small></p>';

    }
?>
```

Comment: PHP is server side, so you aren't going to be able to play an sound using just PHP.

Comment: I can use javascript . but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

Comment: i dont know how to store and compare the value of $title

Comment: That's too broad of a question for StackOverflow, there are dozens if not hundreds of ways to "store and compare a value", especially since there are now 2-3 different languages involved. We also don't know how your site works at all

Comment: I m sorry but i m new on coding. even if i search i do no know how to combine all these that i will find... I just need some help.I thought it would be easy

Comment: In that case, you should try to make a solid attempt at writing the code yourself, and only ask a question here if you have a _specific question_ regarding the solution you are trying to create and cannot solve. We are not a code writing service. Unfortunately, we don't know enough about your platform, existing code, or specific requirements to actually write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way I know is to use Jquery/Ajax
Ensure you have jquery file **jquery.min.js** in your directory. I have also amended your php code to make it work. let me know if you have any issue.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$('#submit').click(function(){
var title='rssfeed';

    $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<span>Please Wait, loading.....</span>');

//you can send data if you like
    var datasend = "title="+ title;

            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'rssfeed.php',
                data:datasend,
                crossDomain: true,
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){

    if(msg=='success'){
    alert('message successfully loaded');
(new Audio('https://notificationsounds.com/soundfiles/8b16ebc056e613024c057be590b542eb/file-sounds-1113-unconvinced.mp3')).play();

    }else{
alert('message loading failed');
}
                    $('#loader').hide();


                }

            });



        //})

    });


    </script>


//Display a loading message...
<div id="loader"></div>
```

**Your php code becomes**

```
<?php
// ensure there is no error message
error_reporting(0);

$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('https://rss.dailyfx.com/feeds/alerts/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array ( 
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y, H:m', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    //echo '<p><strong><a " title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    //echo '<small><em style="color:red; text-align:center;"> '.$date.'</em>    </small></p>';

//They should be only one echo to trigger success or failure actions in other to play the sound at ajax.

echo "success";
    }
?>
```