# Using this code to loop audio in a game, but it does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I used the below code in my JS file for a sliding puzzle game, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var backgroundSound= new Audio("tetris.mp3");
backgroundSound.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
backgroundSound.play();
```

Comment: Potential duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loop` to do that:

```
backgroundSound.loop = true;
```