# How to autoplay sound at javascript page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web system to monitor some values from a database, and I need to play some sound alert when a range of values is received. I've tried a lot of internet samples, but anyone works. The error returned is "`uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first`". The last try was  with the code bellow:

```
<audio id="myAudio" muted="muted">
          <source src="./resources/sound/Alarm.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
<script>
alert(){
    let x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

    if(this.percentIntegral[0]>=70 && this.percentIntegral[0]<=80){
            //alert("play");
            x.play();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: add attribute `autoplay` as  `<audio id="myAudio" muted="muted" <audio id="myAudio" muted="muted">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing audio with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript)

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra, did not work, adding `autoplay`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking this question, I am also suffered from this issue, You can not autoplay audio because the browser needed some interaction with a user after music will autoplay. It's the security purpose of the browser.

The user didn't interact with the document first. It only works when the user interacts with a browser.

You also can not jquery click into the browser. when the user scrolls up down or clicks to any button then after audio will work.

Comment: Yes, @Dhaval Soni is right. You can show some modal on page load and as user clicks on it to close you can play audio. It will work fine.