# Cordova Media plugin pause

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a cordova plugin for playing media but it doesn't work when I pause it. any help would be nice.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('Devive is ready!');
    $('#button').click(function () {
        Player.init();
    });
    $('#playlistid .card a').click(function () {

        const song = new Media('song.mp3')

        if (clicked) {
            song.play();
            $('#' + $(this).data('target')).hide();
            $('.'+$(this).data('target')).show();


            clicked = false;
        } else {
            song.stop();
            $('.' + $(this).data('target')).hide();
            $('#'+$(this).data('target')).show();
            clicked = true;
        }
```

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/how-to-play-audio" Or "https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-media/"

Comment: clicked is not defined