# Having Trouble Playing Audio in Vue Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio

I tried to use the audio tag through the variable, but it didn't explore. Please help me.

This is in tag script

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import data from '../../../data/game3/data2.json'

const music = ref(data.categories[0].units[0].items[0].pronunciation)

console.log(music.value) //when  log it show ../../assets/pronunciation/apple.mp3 which is the right path

</script>
```

And this is in template tag

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ music }}

    <audio controls>
      <source :src="music" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>

    <audio controls>
      <source src="../../assets/pronunciation/apple.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
  </div>
```

The first one is not working can you guys help me please. (I've tried several browsers and they're all the same.)

This is what the browser displays.
[image]

Comment: You're supposed to import files from assets/. Or put them into public folder. This depends on your setup, which is not shown

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure, but I think that in the first audio tag, source is not known in the time of parsing HTML.
Maybe you should call a method `play` on audio element, after it is loaded.

```js
document.querySelector('audio').load();
document.querySelector('audio').play();
```

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/how-to-play-audio).

Comment: I know the solution is I should put the audio files in public because I want to call dynamically, but thank you very much for your help.