# JS .play() on iPad plays wrong file...suggestions?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, audio

So, I am building a web app that has a div with text that changes on various user actions (it's stepping through an array of pieces of text). I'm trying to add audio to it, so I made another array with the sound files in the appropriate positions:

```
var phrases=['Please hand me the awl.','etc1','etc2','etc3'];
var phrasesAudio=['awl.mp3','etc1.mp3','etc2.mp3','etc3.mp3'];
```

And on each action completion, a 'counter' variable in incremented, and each array looks for the object at that counter

```
var audio  = document.createElement("audio"),
canPlayMP3 = (typeof audio.canPlayType === "function" &&
              audio.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") !== "");
function onAction(){
correct++;
document.getElementById('speech').innerHTML=phrases[correct];
if(canPlayMP3){
    snd = new Audio(phrasesAudio[correct]);
}
else{
    snd = new Audio(phrasesAudioOgg[correct]);
}
snd.play();
}
```

(the text replaces a div's HTML and I use .play() for the audio object)...usually works okay (and ALWAYS does in a 'real' browser), but on the iPad (the actual target device) after a few successful iterations, the TEXT continues to progress accurately, but the AUDIO will hiccup and repeat a sound file one or more times. I added some logging and looking there it reports that it's playing `screw.mp3` (just an example, no particular file is more or less error prone), but in actuality it plays `screwdriver.mp3` (the prior file, if there is an error, the audio always LAGS, never LEADS)...because of this I am thinking that the problem is with my use of .play()...so I tried setting `snd=null;` between each sound, but nothing changed...Any suggestions for how to proceed? This is my first use of audio elements so any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

edit: I've also tried setting the files with snd.src (based on https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API) and this caused no audio to play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for iPad you need to call `snd.load()` before `snd.play()` - otherwise you get "odd" behaviour...

see for some insight:
http://jnjnjn.com/187/playing-audio-on-the-ipad-with-html5-and-javascript/ 
[Autoplay audio files on an iPad with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5/3097887#3097887)

EDIT - as per comment from the OP:

Here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox you can find a tip on halting a currently playing piece of media with

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myMediaElementID"); 
mediaElement.pause(); 
mediaElement.src = "";
```

and, following that with setting the correct `src`, `load()`, `play()` works great

Comment: So, while this appeared to work at first (and was a critical piece of it)...it would still act up sometimes. I found, at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox a tip on halting a currently playing piece of media with `var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myMediaElementID");  
mediaElement.pause();  
mediaElement.src = "";` and, following that with setting the correct src, load(), play() works great

Comment: just added it as en EDIT for anyone looking for a solution... thanks :-)