# Play music (in iPhone) just after the page is loaded (using HTML5/JS)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, html5-audio

I found that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src='jQuery.js'></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    document.getElementById("asdf").play();
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio src='music.m4a' id='asdf'></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            setTimeout('document.getElementById("asdf").play();',10000);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio src='music.m4a' id='asdf'></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

will not play the music on iPhone (of course above two works in normal computer), but writing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <audio src='music.m4a' id='asdf'></audio>
        <a href='javascript:document.getElementById("asdf").play()'>dd</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and click on 'dd' will play the music.

My question is : how to automatically play the music right after the page is loaded (and 'ready' to play the music) in iPhone?

PS : I added `setInterval('if($("#asdf").attr("readyState")) console.log(1);');` for check whether the sound is loaded, and I found that `readyState` is changed right after I pressed 'dd'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoplay of video/audio files on iPhones and iPads is not allowed. This is a decision taken by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Try  [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_audio_autoplay.asp)

```
 <audio src='music.m4a' autoplay="autoplay" id='asdf'></audio>
```

Comment: No... it doesn't work on iPhone (even though it works on computer)

Comment: You are right. i have found a same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5 .  .load() method before the .play() method on the audio or video tag should work.

Comment: Or check this: http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/04/14/ipad-and-iphone-html5-video-autoplay/

Comment: Conclusion : In iPhone OS 4.2.1 or higher, there's no way to start audio or video automatically... :(

Answer (score 0):

HTML audio tag has a **autoplay attribute** which specifies whether or not to start playing the audio as soon as the object has loaded.

Check [here](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_audio_tag.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wait until the audio has loaded enough to begin playing it.

[Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#the-ready-states).

Comment: That's why I tried `setTimeout('document.getElementById("asdf").play();',10000);`. It doesn't work even after I added `preload='auto'`. Pressing 'dd' starts the music immediately.