# enable autoplay in ipad

Tags: html

I am working on a project which is in html5. I am testing it in ipad. I have one background audio which play when page load. I made all code to play it, but it not play when it page load. If i click on play button then it play nicely.

Now what i want is to play audio automatically (autoplay). Below is my code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'S6.mp3');
audioElement.controls = true;
audioElement.load();
audioElement.play();



audioElement.play();
$('.play').live('click',function() {
    //alert('play');                     // alert('asdsad');
    audioElement.play();
    $("#play").removeClass("play").addClass("pause");

});
$('.pause').live('click',function() {
//  alert('pause');                    // alert('4545');
    audioElement.pause();
    //$("#play").html('<a href="#" title="Play" class="play" id="play">');

    $("#play").removeClass("pause").addClass("play");


});

$('.soundhover').live('click',function() {
    audioElement.volume=0;
    $("#off").removeClass("soundhover").addClass("soundoff");
});

    $('.soundoff').live('click',function() {
    audioElement.volume=1;
    $("#off").removeClass("soundoff").addClass("soundhover");
});
```

});

Comment: check with this URL http://jnjnjn.com/187/playing-audio-on-the-ipad-with-html5-and-javascript/

Comment: I hope you will get your Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad Audio autoplay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882946/ipad-audio-autoplay)

Answer (score 0):

autoplay doesn't work on iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1