# iPad Audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, audio

I want a simple audio file to play when a web page loads.

```
  var myaudio = new audio("file path .mp3");
  myaudio.play()
```

this works on all the usual browser chrome etc onload but does not play on the ipad, to init this sound I need to use say a onPress function and place the .play code within there and it plays fine.

So how can I have the fiel play onload and nto have a user init via a click? I beleive the mobile safari prevents autoplay but not sure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't automatically play an audio file on the iPad, this is a design decision by Apple. There might be some way around it of course, but autoplaying audio and video is usually not recommended.

See here: [iOS-Specific Considerations](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) (under "User Control of Downloads Over Cellular Networks").

Comment: Thats what I read, but thought I bets ask, as they change their minds so much recently. Thanks

Comment: Fair enough, it's always worth doing so.