# How do videos autoplay on iOS at youtube.com

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

When I set autoplay to true for a YouTube video (IFrame API) on my site, it doesn't work. All the documentation says apple disables autoplay on ios for bandwidth reasons.

However, I see that videos play automatically (without clicking on the video element) on youtube.com on iPad. How did YouTube make it work? It would be hard to imagine Apple does something special just for YouTube.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The OP is asking why autoplay does appear to work if you visit the youtube.com homepage on iOS (it does for me, too).

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Youtube's team uses the interaction of the user when taps/clicks a video button to authorize the reproduction.

Remember that youtube.com is a SPA (Single Page Application) so there is no page reload or redirection.

So, youtube.com doesn't have autoplay enabled.

Comment: So, they're manipulating the DOM and the URL to make it appear as if you are moving between different pages?

Comment: Yes, with plain javascript and managing navigation with "history pushState". Checkout this for more info about autoplay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894406/initialize-videojs-from-dummy-element-using-require-js

Comment: The rules about autoplay has changed, especially in Chrome. Take into account this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide and this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div id="player"> </div> <!--<iframe width="960" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5YptIh_avrM?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>-->

</div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '720',
      width: '960',
      videoId: 'YOUR_ID_HERE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }



  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    event.target.setVolume(20);
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Tested this and it does not work in Safari on iOS 9.1 and Chrome on iOS 9.1

See the answer by Aitor Aznar Álvarez on how YouTube does it on their mobile version.

Comment: I seriously hate ios 9.1.. thank you for the comment, at the moment of writing ios still worked but that was before this "downgrade".

Comment: This works on a laptop / desktop browser. Does not work on mobile iOS browser. May or may not work on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into similar but more complicated issue/requirement.

I need to show YouTube video on a modal popup. Popup is shown on a click.
Have taken YouTube API code (From https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and modified a bit to work with Bootstrap popup.

Below is my code

```
    <div class="modal" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="videoWrapper">
                    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
                    <div id="player"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'YOUR VIDEO ID',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        //event.target.playVideo();// Nullifying the action otherwise the video will play as soon as page loads

    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }

    function ShowPopup() {
        $('#videoModal').modal('show');
        player.playVideo();
    }
    //Stop video when bootstrap popup is closed
    $("#videoModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        player.stopVideo();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

It can't be done. For various reasons (including, but not limited to data usage), Apple doesn't allow auto-playing of videos.

Please refer to:

[Youtube embedded video: autoplay feature not working in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141652/youtube-embeded-video-autoplay-feature-not-working-in-iphone)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it's not a duplicate. The OP is asking why autoplay *does* appear to work if you visit the youtube.com homepage on iOS (it does for me, too).

Answer (score -3):

I haven't tested this, but you may be able to use Javascript and call the play function for the player, or even just click the element when the page has loaded.