# Initialize VideoJS from dummy element using Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, requirejs, video.js

First of all, I explain my requirements:

- I have a dummy element to fire a video -> `<div id="dummyElement"></div>`
- When the user clicks/taps the dummy element, a VideoJS must to be initialized and then have to play the media on most platforms.

Well, my problem is to approach this on IOS when I use **Require.js**  library. This issue force the user to do **two** annoying clicks/taps to view the video.

I have made some examples from a simple example to a example with requirejs and jquery promises.

1- `http://aitoraznar.com/lab/videojs/plain.html` 
 Simple example using HTML5 video tag

2- `http://aitoraznar.com/lab/videojs/complex.html`
 Example using require.js and jQuery promises

3- http://aitoraznar.com/lab/videojs/videojs.html
 Example using VideoJS

4- http://aitoraznar.com/lab/videojs/videojsComplex.html
 Example using VideoJS and require.js and jQuery promises

I can reproduce expected behaviour in the following devices:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-P6200) Android 3.2 - Native browser
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 Android 4.4 - Native browser
- LG Nexus 5 Android 5.0 - Chrome browser
- Blackberry Z10 (STL100-2) - Native browser

Detected devices where doesn't work (Primary IOS):

- iPad Mini 2 (A1489) - IOS 8.1.2 - Safari browser
- iPhone 4  (A1332)- IOS 7.1.2 - Safari browser
- Nokia E7-00 (RM-626) - Symbian Belle 3 (v111.040.1511) - Native browser (8.3) - Java 2.3 - Flash 4.0

I don't know why the 4th example (VideoJS & Require.js) is not working on IOS devices. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Aitor

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problems

Comment: Nope, nothing yet. All people think I'm mad...
But I'll do a try again and I'll post the solution if I find one.

Comment: One solution that i have found works okay, is to load scripts with require when you click the thumbnail of the video, and dont use the callback function of require to start playback, but instead have a setTimeout. This is not fullprof but it works must times

Answer (score 0):

The problem with iOS is you cannot play a video unless you tap it directly. This has nothing to do with RequireJS.

To make this work, instead of using a dummy div that you click, you can use a poster that will mimic the same behavior. You can tweak a little bit the skin to hide what needs to be hidden before the video is clicked.

Comment: I don't want to pre-initialize any VideoJS instance. 
If you take a look to 2nd example, you will see a working example like the 4th but without VideoJS.
This is the reason why I think there is some incompatibility between VideoJS and Require.js

Comment: This is the current status of iOS for the record:
https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/