# youtube play video on click doesnt work on ios devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

apple blocks auto play of videos. And I get it. But really isn't there something I can do to my code to make it play on of an outside div? I am having a hard time accepting the defeat on this one. Don't like the idea "It cant be done". My users are making a conscious choice when they are clicking that play button any way. So its not really a random auto play on page load. Here is my code. Works like charm on a desktop browser. But really would like to make it work on an ios device

```
callMain ();

function playerApp(inputVid) {
    var player = new YT.Player('player', {
      videoId: inputVid,
      width:'100%',
      height:'90%',
      playerVars: {
        rel: 0,
        controls : 2,
        enablejsapi : 1,
        origin : document.domain,
        wmode : "transparent"
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(e) {
    e.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(e) {
    //this removes the player once the video is done
    if(e.data == 0){
        backgroundOverlay(false);
        $('.videoplayer-wrapper').remove();
    }
}

function backgroundOverlay(state){

    var pageHeight = $( document ).height();
    var overlay = '';
    var wrapperHTML = ''
        + '<div class="videoplayer-wrapper">'
            + '<div id="player" class="video-player"></div>'
            + '<div class="videoplayer-close videoplayer-toggle">Close</div>'
        + '</div>';

    if(state){
        overlay = $('body').append('<div class="video-overlay-background" style="height:'+pageHeight+'px;"></div>').append(wrapperHTML);
    }else{
        overlay = $('.video-overlay-background').remove();
    }

    return overlay;
}


function callMain () //$(function(){
    {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var inputVid = '';
    $('.videoplayer-toggle').on('click', function(){
        inputVid = $(this).attr('data-youtubeid');
        backgroundOverlay(true);
        playerApp(inputVid)

        $('.videoplayer-close').on('click', function(){
            backgroundOverlay(false);
            $('.videoplayer-wrapper').remove()
        })

    });
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/zmqj6h1b/

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228858/how-do-videos-autoplay-on-ios-at-youtube-com/29750933

Comment: @AitorAznarÁlvarez -- yeah I did see that while doing my research. The accepted answer doesnt really work. So I would assume that you are pointing me to that post because this can not be done?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't try with Youtube API, only with vanilla/native JS and VideoJS