# how to set embadded video auto play for ipad and iphone

Tags: php, html, html5-video

I've been using YouTube video embedded code. Autoplay = 1 its job is to work with all browser.tis not working for iPad and iPhone. Plz help us?

```
<iframe id="ifem" width="100%" height="350" src="XXXX&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141652/youtube-embedded-video-autoplay-feature-not-working-in-iphone/40961376#40961376)