# Muted video not autoplaying in mobile

Tags: html, css, video, mobile, autoplay

I have a Youtube video that I want to autoplay on my homepage.

https://www.imaritouen.co.jp/newhome/

I understand that mobile browsers limit autoplay unless the video is muted. My embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RT5ijayFPh0?controls=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&mute=1&playlist=RT5ijayFPh0&loop=1" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

The video will autoplay on desktop but not mobile.

I've read a number of blogs and threads on here, including:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5233

[Youtube embedded video: autoplay feature not working in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141652/youtube-embedded-video-autoplay-feature-not-working-in-iphone/8142187#8142187)

[Youtube autoplay not working on mobile devices with embedded HTML5 player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090782/youtube-autoplay-not-working-on-mobile-devices-with-embedded-html5-player)

What am I missing?

EDIT: The settings on my Android browser allow autoplay on muted video.

Comment: it depends on the user settings. By default all videos are blocked on mobile to preserve mobile high-speed traffic. It does not matter if the video is muted or not. The traffic usage comes mainly from the video itself not the audio.

Comment: The settings on my Android phone allow autoplay with muted video, but the video still won't autoplay.

Comment: The video is playing ok on my IOS. When you say it doesn’t play on mobile, is that just on one specific Android device or have you tried it on many?

Comment: I learned that using Youtube requires using an API or else even the URL attribute "autoplay" won't work. I switched to playing the video directly from my server (setting autoplay and muted) and everything works fine.