# how to play one of many sounds in mobile safari / chrome

Tags: html, web-applications, mobile-safari

I want to preload two sound-files and play them on user event.

Trying to do

```
<audio id="ok" src="ok.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="bad" src="bad.mp3"></audio>
```

and later

```
document.getElementById("ok").play();
```

This works only with one file, not two!?

Tried also

```
var au = new Audio('ok.mp3');
au.play();
```

without sucess.

All i dandy in windows / chrome but nothing on the iPod.

Thankful for any cross-browser insight in the matter. (html5).

regards,

Comment: Ok, The problem is not two audio files, but the usage - the second file should autoplay, iOS doesn't allow this. :-|, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow autoplaying. You need listen for some user input, e.g. on button click event and there play a file.