# Safari with audio tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, html5-audio

I am working with HTML5 audio tag with this simple code:

HTML

```
<audio id="audioFrenata">
<source src="sounds/frenata.ogg">
<source src="sounds/frenata.mp3"></audio>
```

JS

```
$('#audioFrenata').on('ended', function() {
        manageImageObjectsLevel();
    }).get(0).play();
```

with Chrome this works as expected, with Safari 5.1.7 on Windows and Safari on iPad 3 I receive this:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#audioFrenata').on('ended', function() {
manageImageObjectsLevel();
}).get(0).play()')
```

Anyone has an idea of why?

Comment: Think `undefined` refers to `stop()` as in stop is not a function on your DOMNode `#audioLevel`. ( `document.getElementById("audioLevel").stop === undefined` )

Comment: where is stop??is you refer to the 'ended' event, even if I eliminate it and only try to call play it will give the same error..

Comment: @Matteo, did you find a solution to this question?

Comment: Not yet..i'm still working on it..

Answer (score 20):

I have had the exact same problem, and I found that it is due to the following restriction in Safari:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user ***may be*** on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, ***preload and autoplay are disabled***. ***No data is loaded until the user initiates it.*** This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html

One way to solve it, is to mute audio by default, and when the user "un-mutes" you can create the instance of an HTML5 Audio object and store that in a "static" / "global" variabel and use that for further playback.

-- UPDATE

Here is a blogpost describing the issue and how to deal with it: http://blog.gopherwoodstudios.com/2012/07/enabling-html5-audio-playback-on-ios.html

Here is a similar stackoverflow question discussing the same thing: [Autoplay audio files on an iPad with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5)

And here follows a JavaScript "module" I have written to use for handling playback of audio in HTML5:

```
NS.modules.html5.audio = (function () {

    var _snd = false;

    function playAudio(src) {
        if (!_snd)
            _snd = new Audio();
        else
            $(_snd).empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            var source = document.createElement('source');
            source.type = src[i].type;
            source.src = src[i].src;
            _snd.appendChild(source);
        }

        _snd.load(); // Needed on safari / idevice
        _snd.play();
    };

    var playAudio = function () {
        var src = [
            { src: "/path/to/audio.wav", type: "audio/vnd.wave" },
            { src: "/path/to/audio.ogg", type: "application/ogg; codecs=vorbis" },
            { src: "/path/to/audio.mp3", type: "audio/mpeg" }
        ];
        playAudio(src);
    };

    return {
        playAudio: playAudio,
        // more play functions here
    };
})();
```

Comment: Wow!!! Nice, yes mobile browsers DO NOT automatically download/play audio files. For a metronome app I made, I had to start with the sound off, and when the user clicked/pressed on the sound icon (which I Had to initially disable) only then would it load and play!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was caused due to HTML format, I switched to the following format and it worked. Hope this helps somebody :

```html
<audio id="audioFrenata" src="sounds/frenata.ogg"></audio>
```

Note the lack of `<source>` element in the above layout.

Comment: This works for me, in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (haven't tested any more). I find it strange though, that's not the format that I've seen used.

Comment: This is not working on Safari with .ogg format. http://jsfiddle.net/q8fze1L3/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by putting `type="audio/mpeg"` before `type="audio/ogg"`.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="your-sound-url" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
  <source src="your-sound-url" type="audio/ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the HTML5 functionality you want is supported in the browsers that you mentioned. You can check it [here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/index.html). Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

ID seems to be wrong.

```
$('#audioLevel').on('ended', function() {
     manageImageObjectsLevel();
}).get(0).play();
```

It suppose to be

```
$('#audioFrenata').on('ended', function() {
     manageImageObjectsLevel();
}).get(0).play();
```

Use below HTML

```
<audio id="audioFrenata"  controls="controls">
    <source src="sounds/frenata.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sounds/frenata.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/F7a4C/)**

Comment: This solves the first problem with the question ( the wrong IDs ) - however, this will not make the iPad automatically playback the audio when visiting the jsFiddle - see my post for clarification ( I have cross checked on the iPad to make sure that it does not automatically playback when invoking `.play()` - as I mention in my post, the user must initiate the playback ;)

Comment: This is still not working on Safari with .ogg format: http://jsfiddle.net/q8fze1L3/