# TypeError: undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myAudio.play()')"

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

Audio file can not play in Safari..
It gives an Error.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'myAudio.play()')
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<audio>
  <source src="audio/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="audio/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Here is my JavaScript Code

```
myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
if (typeof myAudio.loop == 'boolean'){
  myAudio.loop = true;
}
else{
  myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  this.currentTime = 0;
  this.play();
   }, false);
}   
myAudio.play();
```

I have only One Audio Tag in HTML.

Comment: looks like you used 'this' in an event. It's not the same as outside the function declaration. try doing the 'self = this;' just outside and reference the 'self.play()' instead of this.play(). I donno the audio object that well. Is it suppose to give "this"  into the event data? Rereading your intend instead of the pure code. you want to restart. Use "myAudio.play()"  instead of "this.play()" ?

Comment: It seems the **document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]** is returning null. Is your Javascript being defined above the HTML code? It needs to be below your HTML to find the audio element.

Comment: this code is working in Chorme,Opera,Firefox,Konquer....

Comment: @levi nope, its returning the object.

Comment: @levi actually its just snippet of the code... both are taken from different files...

Comment: what is the value of "this" when "this.play()" is executed in Safari specific?

Comment: @MarvinSmit Correct.. :) Now you got the problem...

Comment: Slight typo in question. it's says, 'audio.play()' which i took for abstract, instead of concrete :)

Comment: Could it be the audio formats are not supported on the machine your testing safari on?

Comment: Maybe more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804028/safari-with-audio-tag-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on my windows pc.

So to test, I created a simple HTML file with one red big dot and clicking which would play the audio. It worked on all HTML5 compatible browsers EXCEPT safari. I spent whole day and tried more than 100 different solutions to get it to work on on safari, but no luck.

At the end, I installed QuickTime (latest version) and it solved 50% of the problem.

Rest 50% of the problem was the code structure.

```
<audio id="audio1" src="audio/guestProfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg" ></audio>
<audio id="audio1" src="audio/guestProfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  ></audio>
```

It didn't like the above code. So I had to change it to following:

```
<audio id="audio1">
    <source src="audio/guestProfile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/guestProfile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

This may not be the neat & perfect solution. But it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It will never work on Windows Safari because the last Safari for Windows was released in 2010. And that's the reason why HTML5: `<audio>` or `<video>` tags does not work in Windows Safari. [Test yourself](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)