# Html 5 Audio is not working in iphone safari browser

Tags: jquery, audio, safari, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I'm developing web application that contain audio player functionality.

I'm using html-5 audio tag and its working fine in chrome... but not working in iPhone safari browser.

I'm using color-box jQuery lib for popup slider dialog and in popup I'm playing audio files one by one.( my process is kind of auto play and i'm doing manually) playing first audio then second audio..in one slide want to play 2 audio files.

In popup init function i wrote below code

```
audio1.play();
audio1.on('ended' function(){
audio2.play();
});
```

In iphone safari its not working.(But working in windows and android)
※From second slide its working like pc mode..

Its working fine in PC, but not working in iPhone safari.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html5 (audio) on Safari & iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881807/html5-audio-on-safari-ios)

Comment: actually my requirement is diff..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did like below code and solved problem

Added two lines before play

```
audio1.load();
audio2.load();
```

---

```
audio1.play();
audio1.on('ended' function(){
audio2.play();
});
```