# Is there a way to play a music with <audio> in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I am creating a simple react app that requires playing music with a given url.
I tried to test with a hard coded music url and use the `<audio>` tag to play the music just as we do in HTML.

```
class Music extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <span>

        <audio src="URL">
  </span>

    )
  }
}
```

But this will not compile. What is the simplest way to play a music in a react app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is with `HTML5 Audio`. Create `new Audio` object and control it with custom `Play` / `Pause` buttons.

Basic example:

```js
class Music extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      play: false,
      pause: true,
    }
    this.url = "http://streaming.tdiradio.com:8000/house.mp3";
    this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
  }

  play = () => {
  this.setState({ play: true, pause: false })
    this.audio.play();
  }
  
  pause = () => {
  this.setState({ play: false, pause: true })
    this.audio.pause();
  }
  
  render() {
    
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.play}>Play</button>
      <button onClick={this.pause}>Pause</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Music />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Also you can use `addEventListener` to control and handle `Play` / `Pause`.

**Play:**

```
this.audio.addEventListener('play', () => {
  this.setState({
    play: true,
    pause: false,
  })
});
```

**Pause:**

```
this.audio.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  this.setState({
    play: false,
    pause: true,
  })
});
```

**Documentation and examples:**

[Audio/Video Event Listener](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/media/html5-video-and-audio-element)

[MDN HTML5 Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

**Important note:**

> The `HTML5 Audio` element does not have a `stop()` function, so the audio after pause() is still loading (buffering in background).

This is a solution:
[HTML5 Video: Force abort of buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering)

**JSFIddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/y2j0vzbe/

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I am getting an unexpected token error on the line that has `play = () => {`. Any Idea?

Comment: And I am also confused where to add `<div id="container"></div>`

Comment: @Dawn17 For the first problem see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362292/how-to-use-arrow-functions-public-class-fields-as-class-methods

And for the second one please read react documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom

Comment: Does this work on iOS? I had an almost identical solution, but it doesn't work on Safari on iPhones. It seems like playback needs to be triggered by user action directly, not programatically in another function. [Developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804634/8620945).

Comment: For me it works well. In which part you have a problem? Tested with Expo on Android and iOS.https://expo.io/

Comment: what if I have assign new url on click ? Please  how can I ?