# jQuery: Playing audio on users click on Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, audio

I have this code

```
<button class"play-audio">Play</button>

$(".play-audio").click(function(){
   var audio = new Audio('sample.mp3');
   audio.play();
});
```

As I searched I found that Iphone has bunch of strict rules for playing media without user direct reaction but everyone says that it would work if you play it on user click. The piece of code above works fine on every device and every browser except Iphone!
Does anyone have the same experience or Is there any way to make it work on Iphone?

Comment: This may help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804028/safari-with-audio-tag-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was with the way I was send file through Iphone. I'm using php in backend and I was sending audio as binary not as a file and after sending it as a temp file the problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".play-audio").on("touchstart", function(){
   var audio = new Audio('sample.mp3');
   audio.play();
});
```

try touchstart event