# audio element on iOS 5 not playing

Tags: html, ios5, audio, mobile-safari

I'm trying to play MP3 or Ogg file, I create auto element (without appending it to DOM)

```
var $audio = $('<audio>', {preload: 'auto'}),
audio = $audio.get(0)

audio.src = "url/of/ogg/mp3 file"

audio.play()
```

Audio is not playing on iPad (it plays on desktop however)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the same issue as with Video and I heavily think so:

The problem is, that on mobile iOS devices, Steve Jobs wants you to press play, before a video or audio file is loading. That stops kids from loading huge videos mobile without their explicit permission.

This is a business decicion of Apple. There are currently no workarounds the community is aware of.

Found another SO source: 
[Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009888/autoplay-audio-files-on-an-ipad-with-html5)

Comment: The problem is not in preload or autoplay. Even if I remove preload: auto or append element to DOM it doesn't work. audio.play() - is just command that I call when some button is clicked. I just don't understand why audio doesn't play at all on ipad.

Comment: Try the same without js. Write a normal audio tag with source. And make sure that the iPad is not muted.