# html5 video tag not playing sound in my IPAD?

Tags: html, ipad

I am using html5 video tag to play a  video file, i am using below code to play my videos,

```
<video src="../Videos/File1.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="video1" controls="controls">
<p>Your browser does not support the video.</p>
</video>
```

here, when i run this code in my Ipad, I am able to see the video playing, but i am unable to get the sound,

any help why the sound is not playing..

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908724/html5-video-on-ipad

Hope this link might help.